# Xcode debugger doesn't stop at breakpoint in watchOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos, watchos-simulator, xcode-debugger

I've set a breakpoint in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method in the  `WKExtensionDelegate` class.

**WatchExtensionDelegate.h**

```
@interface WatchExtensionDelegate : NSObject<WKExtensionDelegate>
@end
```

**WatchExtensionDelegate.m**

```
@implementation WatchExtensionDelegate

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive {
    [self refreshView]; // Breakpoint
    [self refreshData];
}

...

@end
```

**Screenshot of breakpoint**

[image: Screenshot of breakpoint]

---

The app works as intended. But the debugger doesn't stop. I use Xcode 9.4.1